# How do I get this result using a php loop?

Tags: php, loops, math

I am trying to get the following result:-

```
1/1
1/2
1/3
1/4
1/5
1/6
1/7
1/8
1/9

2/1
2/2
2/3
```

Etc, up until 345 (the first number).

I can't get the desired result, this is what I have tried so far:

```
$start = 1;
$end = 345;

$start1 = 1;
$end1 = 9;

for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++){
  $i1 = '';
  for($i1 = $start1; $i1 <= $end1; $i1++){
    $tweedearray .= $i1.'<br>';
  }
    $eerstearray .= $i.'/'.$i1.'<br>';
}

echo $eerstearray;
```

Comment: The only way to learn is to do it yourself. This is not difficult, so you can do it. Look at it again, a bit more careful, and try to find out why it does what it does. TIP: Don't do this assignment: `$i1 = '';`, it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one

```
$tweedearray = "";$eerstearray = "";
$start = 1;
$end = 345;

$start1 = 1;
$end1 = 9;

for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++){
  $i1 = '';
  for($i1 = $start1; $i1 <= $end1; $i1++){
    $tweedearray .= $i1.'<br>';
    $eerstearray .= $i.'/'.$i1.'<br>';
  }
}

echo $eerstearray;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$firstCurrent = 1;
$firstEnd = 345;

$lastStart = 1;
$lastEnd = 9;
$lastCurrent = $lastStart;

// Loop the current first number until we are finished
while ($firstCurrent <= $firstEnd) {
    // Loop the last number until we are finished
    while ($lastCurrent <= $lastEnd) {
        echo $firstCurrent . '/' . $lastCurrent . PHP_EOL;

        // Increase the last number with one
        $lastCurrent++;
    }

    // Increase the first number with one
    $firstCurrent++;

    // Reset the last number to the start number
    $lastCurrent = $lastStart;

    // Print an empty line
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Try it online here](https://3v4l.org/PNeiv)

Answer (score 0):

It is some silly mistakes.
You didn't declare the variables $tweedearray and $eerstearray. (And I don't Know why you want the first variable as you are not using it in your code)
And you put this `$eerstearray .= $i.'/'.$i1.'<br>';` outside the for loop. Put it inside the second loop and you will get the out put.

```
// $tweedearray = '';
$eerstearray = '';
$start = 1;
$end = 345;

$start1 = 1;
$end1 = 9;

for($i = 1; $i <= 345; $i++){
  for($i1 = 1; $i1 <= 9; $i1++){
   // $tweedearray .= $i1.'<br>';
    $eerstearray .= $i.'/'.$i1.'<br>';
  }

}

echo $eerstearray;
```